# Remote Desktop Services roaming profile leaving local copy after logoff

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, roaming-profile

I have a Windows 2008 Remote Desktop Server and a GPO redirecting Remote Desktop Services profiles to a netapp share. This works with one caveat. I am getting a local profile written as well as the roaming profile. An actual full local profile, not a cached copy.

I have already tried deleting the registry key and local profile directories manually. They just reappear on login.

Comment: There's a GPO setting to delete cached copies of roaming profiles. Do you have that setting enabled in the GPO that is being applied to the RDS server?

Comment: great! where is the setting?

Comment: I found it in Computer Configuration \ Policies \ Administrative Templates \ System \ User Profiles.  Its called "Delete cached copies of roaming profiles"

Comment: unfortunately this did not work - the profile is not cached.  its an actual local profile.  I will adjust my question.

Comment: What property sheet are you using to specify the roaming profile location?

Comment: on a DC, Computer Configuration \ Policies \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Remote Desktop Services \ Remote Desktop Session Host \ Profiles     I have enabled both "Set path for Remote Desktop Services Roaming User Profile" and "Use mandatory profiles on the RD Session Host server"

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "Delete cached copies of roaming profiles" setting in the GPO that is applied to the RDS server. The setting can be found at:

Computer Configuration|Policies|Administrative Templates|System|User Profiles

Comment: This did not work - but I left the setting in place

Comment: did you run gpupdate on the server after setting the GPO setting? If not, do that or reboot the server.

Comment: I did reboot, but it did not help